# Using u-law compression for audio files on Windows 7

Tags: c, windows, audio, wasapi

I need to convert some hi res audio files to u-law compression. I find no documentation on this- I'm almost certain the codec is there on Windows machines, but how the heck do I access it?

Comment: What language, framework, etc. are you using? Are you just looking for a Win32 function?

Comment: Code is in C, I'm using WASAPI calls and the current Visual Studio.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes the codec is there, however it is outside of WASAPI. APIs that deal with codecs are:

- [Audio Compression Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd797805%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
- DirectShow
- Media Foundation

Not sure about the latter, however the first two have the μ-law encoder readily available (the codec itself has ACM interface, and DirectShow offers a [wrapper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373410%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) over it).